# Toggle Chosen Select With JQuery Validate Plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I've been researching and wrestling with this for days, so finally I turn to StackOverflow when I'm at my wits' end! Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

When a user toggles a radio button, it enables a Chosen select, and if they do or do not make a selection, jQuery Validate works accordingly - i.e.: if the Chosen select is disabled, jQuery Validate ignores it, and if it's enabled, it checks to see an option is selected. If the user has the Chosen Select enabled, but then decides to remove an option and does NOT toggle the Chosen Select via the radio button to disable it, I want the validation to trigger.

So far, it works fine until you perform the following steps:

1. First, click "No" to enable the Chosen select. Hitting submit will trigger the validation as expected.
2. Next, add an option to the select - now the form validates correctly.
3. Then, remove the option - again, the validation triggers as expected.
4. Now toggle the radio button to "Yes" - the field will disable, but the validation error message will not dismiss (minor issue)
5. Toggle the radio back to "No", do not select anything in the Chosen select, and hit submit - validation does not trigger again. Additionally, adding and removing options from this point forward will not trigger the validation.

I've created a Fiddle of my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6YBU/1/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I know I'm close, but unfortunately my JQuery/JS skills aren't advanced enough to see the problem here.

HTML Markup (Please note I'm using Bootstrap 1.4.0)

```
<form name="documentAdmin" id="documentAdmin">
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="SendToAll">Send To All:</label>
    <div class="input">
        <ul class="inputs-list">
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input name="SendToAll" id="SendToAll_Y" type="radio" value="Yes" checked> <span>Yes</span>

                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input name="SendToAll" id="SendToAll_N" type="radio" value="No"> <span>No</span>

                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="noticeSentTo">Workgroups:</label>
    <div class="input">
        <select name="noticeSentTo" class="span11" id="noticeSentTo" multiple data-placeholder="Select At Least One Workgroup" disabled>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Option One</option>
            <option value="2">Option Two</option>
            <option value="3">Option Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn success" name="SaveDocSet" value="SubmitSave" id="SubmitSave">Save And Preview</button>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#noticeSentTo").chosen();
$("input[name=SendToAll]").click(function () {
    $("#noticeSentTo").removeAttr('disabled').trigger("liszt:updated").chosen().change(checkerrors).parents("div.clearfix").addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "SendToAll_Y") {
        $("#noticeSentTo").val('').attr('disabled', 'disabled').trigger("liszt:updated").chosen().change(checkerrors).parents(".error").removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});

var validator = $("#documentAdmin").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorClass: 'help-inline',
    validClass: 'success',
    errorElement: 'span',
    ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn-done)',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":hidden")) {
            element.next().parent().append(error);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }

    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents("div.clearfix").addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents(".error").removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    rules: {
        noticeSentTo: {
            required: "#SendToAll_N:checked",
            minlength: 1
        }
    },
    messages: {
        noticeSentTo: {
            required: "If not sending to all Members, at least one Workgroup must be selected",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    }
});
var checkerrors = function () {
    validator.form();
    console.log(validator.numberOfInvalids());
    validator.showErrors();
};
var chosen = $('#noticeSentTo').chosen().change(checkerrors);
```

});

UPDATE: I added some CSS to the Fiddle to better see the validation states, and more importantly, when it fails to validate after removing an option from the select.

Comment: Without some CSS in your jsFiddle... its hard to tell when validation is occurring.

Comment: The validation message appears, but I see your point - I'll update the Fiddle at least with the error and success classes so they get styled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Chosen plugin, after following your steps, automatically selects the empty option.  Normally, jQuery Validate is smart enough to figure out that this is not a valid selection and would not count it towards the minlength, but I guess in the case of multiple selects, it is not so brilliant.

What you need then, is a smarter validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "multipleSelectOptionsSelected",
  function (value, element, param) {
      if (this.optional(element)){
          return true;
      }

      var selectedOptions = 0;
      $('option:selected',element).each(function(){
          if (this.value != ''){
           selectedOptions++;   
          }
      });
      return selectedOptions >= param;
  },
    'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

Then in your rules/messages, refer to the new method instead of `minlength`:

```
   rules: {
        noticeSentTo: {
            required: "#SendToAll_N:checked",
            multipleSelectOptionsSelected: 1
        }
    },
    messages: {
        noticeSentTo: {
            required: "If not sending to all Members, at least one Workgroup must be selected",
            multipleSelectOptionsSelected: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/r6YBU/4/

Demo of jQuery Validate not doing smart things with multiple selects with an empty option:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/utrcF/

And I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/824) for you on jQuery Validate.

Comment: Ryley, you are awesome! Thank you so much for not only solving the problem, but also explaining WHY it's happening - that helps a lot in understanding the whole concept.

Comment: I'll award the bounty tomorrow - it won't let me for another 19 hours :(